# How to use model in rails in thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

```
class Auction::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "auction_users"
end

class Auction::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "auction_products"

  def insert_data
      Thread.start{
        Auction::User.create(:product_id => self.id)
      }
  end
end
```

Something like this. When I use a Thread in a model and at the same time use another model in the Thread, uninitialized constant Auction::Product::Auction (NameError) presents . Why and how to solve it?

totally ruined. Help!!!

Comment: Post the tread class also. I think you should rethink the design. Auction has_many users Products belongs_to Auction. The rails slogan is convention before configuration. If you get stuck, usually you're not following the convention

Comment: rails are not async. to do tasks in background one should probably use delayed_job or something similar.